# Is there an example of $F_{\sigma}$ set in $[0,1]$ with empty interior and with measure $1$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is there an example of  $F_{\sigma}$ set in $[0,1]$ with empty interior and with measure $1$? I wonder if it exists.

Comment: Isn't it the case that all closed sets in $[0,1]$ with empty Interior are countable? So countable unions are them are also countable, and have zero measure? (Perhaps I didn't think this through properly...)

Comment: @KennyWong The Cantor set is closed and has empty interior, but is uncountable. (And the "fat" Cantor set has the same properties and even has positive measure.)

Comment: In other words, you want to know if there is a set whose **complement** is a dense $G_\delta$ set with measure $0$? Yes, I think there is such a set. For each natural $n$ construct a dense open set of measure $\lt\frac1n$; the intersection of those sets is a dense $G_\delta$ set of measure zero; subtract that set from $[0,1].$

Comment: I guess it's worth to consider $[0,1] \cap \Bbb Q$ and it's complement on $[0,1]$…

Comment: @Gono What does that do for us? $[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q$ is a dense $F_{\sigma}$ but has measure zero. Its complement is dense and has full measure, but it is a $G_{\delta}$, not an $F_{\sigma}$. I think the construction by bof is the right way to proceed here.

Comment: @Bungo Yes, good point!

Comment: @bungo You are totally right…

Comment: $$A=[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q$$

Since the set of irrational is dense in [0,1] then A has empty interior.
on the other hand, the set of rational number is countable so the complement of A in [0,1] has zero measure.  therefore, 
$$\overset{\circ}{\Bbb Q^c} = \emptyset  \implies \overset{\circ}{A} = \emptyset $$

AND since  $\Bbb Q$ is Countable 

$$|\Bbb Q|=0\implies |A| =0$$
$$1=|[0,1]|   = | [0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q |+| [0,1]\cap\Bbb Q| = |[0,1]\setminus\Bbb Q|= |A|$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. As the commenters have mentioned, it suffices by complementation to construct a dense $G_\delta$ set of measure zero.

In fact, you can also do this on the entire real line! Let $(q_n)$ be an enumeration of the rationals. Define the set $$E_i = \bigcup_{j\in \mathbb{N}} B(q_j,1/2^{i+j}).$$ Then $E_i$ is a dense open set of Borel measure at most $1/2^i$, and $E_k \subseteq E_i $ for $k>i$. It follows (edit: from the Baire Category Theorem) that $\bigcap_i E_i$ is a dense, $G_\delta$, null set.

Comment: Very good. Nitpick: the observation that $E_k\subseteq E_i$ for $k\gt i$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Why do we need the Baire Category theorem? $\cap E_i$ includes all the rationals, so it must be dense. And the decreasing measure of the $E_i$ converging to zero ensures the result is a null set.